# executionContextCreated has invalid 'context' error running Selenium and ChromeDriver in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
EXE_PATH = r'C:\Users\chris\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=EXE_PATH)
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Error Message even though I set my path:

```
executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"EF256666E4D81997909BDF6BF23E3170","isDefault":true,"type":"default"},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)
```

Comment: you need to update your chromedriver version. The current driver is not compatible with chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"EF256666E4D81997909BDF6BF23E3170","isDefault":true,"type":"default"},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.15*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.15*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.15/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v40-43**

- You are using *chrome=83.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v83.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt) clearly mentions:

> Supports **Chrome version 83**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.15* and the *Chrome Browser v83.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v83.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 83.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v83.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.